# Docker registry in Artifactory doesn't keep untagged images

Tags: docker, artifactory

I wonder if there is a way to keep untagged images in JFrog **Artifactory**.

When I push the first image with a tag `1.1` for example I get a digest of that image.

If I pull the image with `docker pull my-docker.jfrog.io/myimage@$digest_from_first_image` it works just fine.

But if I push another image with the same tag `1.1` which will likely have another digest,  the old digest is deleted and no longer available. I get the error `not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry.`

Comment: This seems expected because the image is overridden.

Comment: I don't think the image itself and its layers should be overridden. From my understanding just the tag should be updated pointing to the new digest and the old image should be kept intact, just untagged.

Comment: I just did a quick test in Docker hub and it works the way I'd expect. After tag is overridden I still can pull untagged images using digests.

docker.io/ericopf/java - It has only the latest tag but 2 digests:

docker pull docker.io/ericopf/java@sha256:f5cd4185afc6869da228489bd66ac19f37313f3af23ec5727fda1e03dfd4ea0b
docker pull docker.io/ericopf/java@sha256:68d8b689858f2ab510b725b5db482f1313edc1ad87b0a315a0075c5c05ddddf2

Comment: what i assume is as the user has override permission, therefore, the docker image is getting overridden and the digest is also overridden with the new one.